# Firefox Extension Menuitem Image Doesn't Display

Tags: image, firefox-addon, xul, menuitem

I'm working on a Firefox extension that creates a menu of bookmarks from data fetched from a server. I'd like to add icons to each menuitem, but I can't seem to get them to display. I'm creating each menuitem using:

```js
Bookmarks.createMenuItem = function(item) {
    var menuItem = document.createElementNS(Bookmarks.XUL_NS, "menuitem");
    menuItem.setAttribute("label", item.url_title);
    menuItem.setAttribute("oncommand", "Bookmarks.openUrl('" + item.url + "');");
    menuItem.setAttribute("class", "bookmark-menu-item");
    if ( item.favicon ) {
            menuItem.setAttribute("class", menuItem.getAttribute("class") +
                                   " menuitem-iconic");
            menuItem.setAttribute("image", item.favicon);
    }

    return menuItem;
};
```

The menuitem works just fine except that it doesn't display the image. I've verified the URLs that I'm getting for each image (from item.favicon in the code below) are accessible.

Any idea what's wrong here? I'm using Firefox 6.0.2.

Comment: Are you fetching images on-the-fly from external server from the web? If yes, I'm not sure if this is allowed for security reasons. Maybe try storing them locally as base64-encoded strings (it's just a wild guess).

Comment: I just put a 16x16 icon.png in my extension's content directory, then tried the following for the image attribute: "icon.png", "content/icon.png", "bookmarks/content/icon.png", "chrome://bookmarks/content/icon.png". I also tried setting it via menuItem.image instead of using setAttribute(). None of that seemed to work. I put some alerts in to verify that the image attribute is set on the menuitem, and that it has a "menuitem-iconic" class.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see anything wrong with your code here. Setting `menuitem-iconic` class and `image` attribute definitely works for me.

Comment: This appears to have something to do with running Firefox on Ubuntu. I installed the extension in Firefox on a Windows box at work (using my original code) and the icons show up just fine! Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've picked random extension that has icons in menu items - [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/httpfox/) - and there you have something like this:

in XUL file:

```xml
<menupopup id="toolsPopup">
    <menu id="hf_menu_HttpFox" 
        class="menu-iconic" 
        label="&browseroverlay.menutools.httpfox.label;" />
</menupopup>
```

in CSS file:

```css
#hf_appmenu_HttpFox, #hf_menu_HttpFox, #hf_menu_webDeveloper_HttpFox {
    list-style-image: url(chrome://httpfox/skin/globe16.png);
}
```

In [FoxSplitter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fox-splitter-formerly-split-br/) it's the same way.

So basically, if `style` attribute is allowed for menus, you may change

```js
menuItem.setAttribute("image", item.favicon);
```

to

```js
menuItem.setAttribute("style", "list-style-image: url(" + item.favicon + ")");
```

(if `item.favicon` is the URL), or if `style` doesn't work, then create classes for each item.
Hope this helps.

Comment: `image` attribute and `list-style-image` CSS property are completely equivalent in this case.